# How to use raster package in python with rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

Working with R in Python using rpy2 on windows 7.
I need to open some rasters as RasterLayer using the function raster() from the raster package. I manage to install the package, but not to use its function.

I install the packages that I need (rgdal, sp, raster, lidR, io) using

```
utils.install_packages(StrVector(names_to_install))
```

`names_to_install` is a list of the packages that are still not installed. This works fine.

I know how to try the "basic" functions, like sum, and it works:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
function_sum = robjects.r['sum']
```

But the same doesn't seem to work with the raster function from the raster package:

```
function_raster = robjects.r['raster']
```

since I get the error:

```
LookupError: 'raster' not found
```

I also tried the following:

```
raster_package = importr('raster')
```

with the intention to be able to run the next and load my raster file:

```
raster_package.raster(my_raster_file)
```

but the first line (import('raster')) causes the crash of python and I get the error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

This doesn't happen with other loaded packages like rgdal, but with the raster package and with the lidR package I get the error.

I looked up this error, seems to be access violation, but I don't know what I can do about it and why it only happens with certain packages.

I expect to be able to call the raster function from the package raster.

**Edit**

I tried it on a computer with windows 10 and the error doesn't show anymore when running

```
raster_package = importr('raster')
```

Still would be nice to know what is the problem with Windows 7 and if there is any solution.

Answer (score 0):

`rpy2` does not currently have Windows support. This is not a final situation, most of what is likely needed is contributions to finalize this: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/blob/master/rpy2/rinterface_lib/embedded_mswin.py